# Unable to run SQL script from command line

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, dump

I tend to reinstall an API locally for development and testing purpose, and I wish to script the commands.
Therefore, I try to replace the step where I run the SQL script through `MySQL Workbench` > `Run SQL Script...` > `DumpFile.sql` by its equivalent command line.

Here's what I've got so far :

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
unzip Dump20200513.sql.zip
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p password —port=9906 database < Dump20200513.sql
docker-compose exec php /bin/sh
```

The line with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p password —port=9906 database < Dump20200513.sql` doesn't seem to be working :

```
➜  web_api_symfony git:(resolvers) ✗ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p password —port=9906 database < Dump20200513.sql

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysql mariadb-client client client-server client-mariadb
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults          Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults             Don't read default options from any option file.
The following specify which files/extra groups are read (specified before remaining options):
--defaults-file=#         Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=#   Read this file after the global files are read.
--defaults-group-suffix=# Additionally read default groups with # appended as a suffix.

  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --abort-source-on-error
                      Abort 'source filename' operations in case of errors
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  --auto-vertical-output
                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
                      result is wider than the terminal width.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      (Enables --silent.)
  --binary-as-hex     Print binary data as hex
  --character-sets-dir=name
                      Directory for character set files.
  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                      default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                      with --comments.
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
  -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
  -D, --database=name Database to use.
  --default-character-set=name
                      Set the default character set.
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
  -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file.)
  -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
  -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error. Sets
                      abort-source-on-error to 0
  -G, --named-commands
                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
                      internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
                      named commands can be used from any line of the query,
                      otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
                      Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
                      disabled by default.
  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
  --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MariaDB server.
                      Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
  --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
  -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
  -X, --xml           Produce XML output.
  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)
  -L, --skip-line-numbers
                      Don't write line number for errors.
  -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.
  --column-names      Write column names in results.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)
  -N, --skip-column-names
                      Don't write column names in results.
  --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).
  -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
                      default database is the one named at the command line.
  --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you don't supply an
                      option, the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
                      PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
                      etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
                      work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
                      option is disabled by default.
  -p, --password[=name]
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's asked from the tty.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
                      /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --progress-reports  Get progress reports for long running commands (like
                      ALTER TABLE)
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-progress-reports to disable.)
  --prompt=name       Set the command line prompt to this value.
  --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe).
  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
                      down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
                      history file.
  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.
  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is lost. Disable with
                      --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      each row on new line.
  -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.
  --ssl               Enable SSL for connection (automatically enabled with
                      other flags).
  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
                      --ssl).
  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).
  --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation list (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path (implies --ssl).
  --tls-version=name  TLS protocol version for secure connection.
  --ssl-verify-server-cert
                      Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
                      hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
                      default.
  -t, --table         Output in table format.
  --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)
                      also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
                      --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.
  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
  --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds before connection timeout.
  --max-allowed-packet=#
                      The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
                      server.
  --net-buffer-length=#
                      The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.
  --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.
  --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using
                      --safe-updates.
  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol.
  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.
  --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.
  --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.
  --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.
  --binary-mode       By default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is
                      translated to '\n'. This switch turns off both features,
                      and also turns off parsing of all clientcommands except
                      \C and DELIMITER, in non-interactive mode (for input
                      piped to mysql or loaded using the 'source' command).
                      This is necessary when processing output from mysqlbinlog
                      that may contain blobs.
  --connect-expired-password
                      Notify the server that this client is prepared to handle
                      expired password sandbox mode even if --batch was
                      specified.

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
abort-source-on-error             FALSE
auto-rehash                       TRUE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE
binary-as-hex                     FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
delimiter                         ;
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
init-command                      (No default value)
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              127.0.0.1
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              0
progress-reports                  FALSE
prompt                            \N [\d]>
protocol
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         FALSE
socket                            (No default value)
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-crl                           (No default value)
ssl-crlpath                       (No default value)
tls-version                       (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
table                             FALSE
user                              user
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
connect-expired-password          FALSE
➜  web_api_symfony git:(resolvers) ✗
```